# Select element in Chrome Dev Tools not working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the Chrome DevTools console to try to select elements in this page: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=The+DIAMOND+(DHA+Intake+And+Measurement+Of+Neural+Development)+Study%3A+a+double-masked%2C+randomized+controlled+clinical+trial+of+the+maturation+of+infant+visual+acuity+as+a+function+of+the+dietary+level+of+docosahexaenoic+acid

But I'm finding that everything I try to select returns null. For example, if I type `$('body')` into the console, it returns null:

[image]

Why is this happening? There is definitely a `<body>` tag in the page.

And the same `$('body')` query in the console on other sites returns an element.

Comment: Ah - I think perhaps the JavaScript on the site has redefined `$`. Is this the explanation?

Comment: @DaveBurn it's usually possible to query elements in the console using the `$` shortcut - that's what my question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this site overwrites `$` funtion. use `jQuery` instead.

```
jQuery('body'); //Object { 0: <body>, context: HTMLDocument → pubmed, selector: "body", length: 1 }
```